# Disable jquery function when screen width larger than 480

Tags: jquery, width, screen

I'm a newbie (no kidding?!) and I can't get this to work. What am I doing wrong here?
If the screen width is larger than 480 I don't want this function to do anything, only to fire when screen width is 480 and below.

```
if ( screen.availWidth < 480 ) {

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".reklam").click(function(){
 $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');

  });
});

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because screen size can change (if a user re-sizes the window), would it be more relevant to have the if statement within the event?

See example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reklam").click(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great stuff!  Be sure to accept as the answer if this helped.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I would check the `screen width`1 directly inside the function as shown below:

```
$(".reklam").click(function(){
  var screenWidth = screen.width;
  if (screenWidth <= 480) {
      $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');
  }  else {
       alert('Screen width too high!');
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".reklam").click(function(event){
     if ( screen.availWidth < 480 ) {
         $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');
    }
    else {
         event.stopPropagation();
         return false;
    }
 });
});
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
     var winWidth = 0; 
    $(window).resize(function() {
     winWidth = $(document).width();
    });
```

in your function write

```
if(winWidth >480)
{
  $(".reklam").click(function(){
 $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');
});

}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reklam").click(function(){
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $('.reklam').attr('src','bilder/480/reklam_on.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```