# Disable jQuery Based on Screen Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to disable the following JavaScript if a screen size is `< 601px`:

```
$(function() {
  function rotate() {
    $('#homemaincontent div').last().fadeOut(2000, function() {
      $(this).insertBefore($('#homemaincontent div').first()).show();
    });
   }
     setInterval(function() {
     rotate();
     }, 7000);
});
```

I found the following page with what seemed like a good answer, but I can't get it work:

[Disable jquery function when screen width larger than 480](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499953/disable-jquery-function-when-screen-width-larger-than-480?newreg=06d19576a3224bfeb15ee237e23c2d7d)

Comment: Edited my answer so it can display a static image as well based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  function rotate() {
    $('#homemaincontent div').last().fadeOut(2000, function() {
      $(this).insertBefore($('#homemaincontent div').first()).show();
    });
   }
     setInterval(function() {
         if(Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) > 601)
             rotate();
     }, 7000);
    });
```

so now each time rotate is called it will first check if the viewport width is more than 601 and if it is it will execute the function.

If you dont want to adjust for responsive behaviour you can just put that if statement to run at the begining of `$(function(){ insert if () run rest of code else do nothing}`and it will only evaluate once when your script runs for the first time

**EDIT**
To answer about your 2nd question in the comment

Create a staticImageX css class and a DynamicImageX class
that will have the needed css like position, width, top etc.
Use jquery and the above expression to test against the width again
and run jquery code to adjust the class on the image container on the same intervan as your rotate function
So

```
if(width > 601)
    $('#imageContainer').addClass('DynamicImageX').removeClass('staticImageX')
else 
    $('#imageContainer').addClass('staticImageX').removeClass('DynamicImageX')**
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Is there anyway to display a static image if the screen is less than 601?

Comment: sure. create 2 css classes that each will handle the css needed for each case for the image container.
So create a staticImageX css class and a DynamicImageX class
Use jquery and the above expression to test against the width again
and run jquery code to adjust the class on the image container on the same intervan as your rotate function

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to detect the browser viewport:

```
if($( window ).width() > 601){
    // function
}
```

In case you want to detect the width of your HTML document:

```
if($( document ).width() > 601){
    // function
}
```

Based on your comment on another answer, you'd be able to add a static image instead like this:

```
$(function() {
    function rotate() {
        $('#homemaincontent div').last().fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(this).insertBefore($('#homemaincontent div').first()).show();
        });
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        if($( window ).width() > 601){
            rotate();
        } else {
            var staticIMG =  document.getElementById('staticIMG');
            if (typeof(staticIMG) != 'undefined' && staticIMG != null){
                return false;
            } else {
                $("<img id='staticIMG' src='your/static/image.png'>").insertBefore($('#homemaincontent div').first()).show();
            }
        }
    }, 7000);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. When I inspect the element, the script is still running and places the new static image before all others in the HTML and continues to just add the same static image over and over in the HTML. However, I never actually see the desired image on the screen itself. Thoughts?

Comment: @Jacob I've changed the script so it will only add the image once. If you're not seeing the image, you should make sure the `src='your/static/image.png'` contains the correct path to the image you're trying to show.

Answer (score 1):

Include the following jQuery-plugin:

```
/*! viewportSize | Author: Tyson Matanich, 2013 | License: MIT */
(function(n){n.viewportSize={},n.viewportSize.getHeight=function(){return t("Height")},n.viewportSize.getWidth=function(){return t("Width")};var t=function(t){var f,o=t.toLowerCase(),e=n.document,i=e.documentElement,r,u;return n["inner"+t]===undefined?f=i["client"+t]:n["inner"+t]!=i["client"+t]?(r=e.createElement("body"),r.id="vpw-test-b",r.style.cssText="overflow:scroll",u=e.createElement("div"),u.id="vpw-test-d",u.style.cssText="position:absolute;top:-1000px",u.innerHTML="<style>@media("+o+":"+i["client"+t]+"px){body#vpw-test-b div#vpw-test-d{"+o+":7px!important}}<\/style>",r.appendChild(u),i.insertBefore(r,e.head),f=u["offset"+t]==7?i["client"+t]:n["inner"+t],i.removeChild(r)):f=n["inner"+t],f}})(this);
```

And use it like this:

```
if (viewportSize.getWidth() > 600) {
//your function goes here
}
```

Comment: I got it to work using your additional script, but I already have my own jQuery plugin, so thank you. However, if I wanted to add an else statement afterwards that made it so a static image was displayed, how would I do that?

Comment: Just add an `else { //code for displaying image here }` after the closing bracket for the if? Depending on how you want to display the image, you could either just add a class to a container, or create and populate a HTML element.